# Usage of '*' in the item list of a select statement, e.g. SELECT * vs. SELECT *,a vs SELECT a,*

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering what might be the reason why MySQL implements the usage of '*' in the field list of a SELECT statement in the following way...

The [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) says that:

> The list of select_expr terms comprises the select list that indicates
>   which columns to retrieve. Terms specify a column or expression or can
>   use *-shorthand:
>
> - A select list consisting **only of a single unqualified *** can be used as
>     shorthand to select all columns from all tables
>
>   SELECT * FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ...
>
> ...

It seems to be strict that '*' can be used only once in the field list, and once it is, nothing else should be there. It also conforms the SQL 1999 standard (and probably 2011 too):

```
<select list> ::=
<asterisk>
| <select sublist> [ { <comma> <select sublist> }... ]
```

However, the MySQL grammar implements the usage of '*' as follows (code snippet from recent version of MySQL, sql_yacc.cc):

```
select_item_list:
          select_item_list ',' select_item
        | select_item
        | '*'
        ;
```

... and this implementation is more permissive!! For instance, it *allows* the execution of the following query:

```
SELECT *, a FROM t
```

But, it *does not allow* the execution of the following queries:

```
SELECT a,* FROM t
SELECT *,* FROM t
```

Does someone have an example what might be the reason for this MySQL extension of the standard?

Comment: other sql implementations allow the `a, *` form. MySql allows `*, a`. I don't understand your question.

Comment: `SELECT *, a_field as another_field FROM my_table`

Comment: what is meant by "makes sense"? They are 2 vendor specific implementations that both "make sense" to me.

Comment: Well I agree, 'makes sense' might be 'fuzzy' in the question... So MySQL allows `*,a`, the standard allows only `*`. One reason I think that using `*,a` might be what Matteo proposed as an example, to have one field or some expression (e.g a+b) aliased in the result set. But it does not explain why `a,*` is not permitted. So I thought there might be something else here... e.g. some earlier standards or something.

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL parser appears to partially parse and validate the query, and then basically ignores anything after the `SELECT *` but before `FROM` for the result set.  [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a60633/1)

Note that `select *, id from myTable;` has only one output column.  So does `select *, id, id, id, id from myTable;`.  It's almost like the query engine gets a distinct list of columns and goes from there.  MySQL generally seems to do things like this; make assumptions about what the user wants.  Most other RDBMSs will throw errors instead of doing exactly what the user specifies in a deterministic way.

In any case, *no* RDBMS implements SQL strictly according to any ANSI SQL.  It's both too difficult and too impractical.

Comment: if I try `select *, id+1 from myTable` id+1 is included in the result set, so MySQL does not really ignore anything there, but I think I understand and agree that MySQL seems to 'make assumptions about what the user wants'